# Problema con Mala Leída de Caracteres en Español - Python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de obtener partes textuales de un sitio en español (utilizando los módulos de **requests** y **bs4**). El conflicto ocurre que al leer la web haciendo el **print()** los carácteres de tildes se muestran raros ...:

""" *Villa MaipÃº, Buenos Aires* """ es por ejemplo una línea de la shell.

O sea que existen partes que tendrían que corregirse, ya que:

> Ã debería ser É
>
> Ã± debería ser ñ
>
> Ã­- debería ser í
>
> ... etc.

¿Cómo puedo arreglar eso para que se muestren correctamente?

Muchas gracias.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Encoding: UTF-8
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

print("--------------------------")
print("--------- Neuvoo ---------")
print("--------------------------")
url = "https://neuvoo.com.ar/trabajos/?k=&l=capital+federal&p=1&date=&field=&company=&source_type=&radius=&from=&test=&iam=&is_category=no"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print("### Descripcion ###")
for extraccion in soup.find_all ('div', class_='j-snippet'):
    extraccion = extraccion.text
    if not (extraccion == ''):
        print(extraccion)
print("### Locacion ###")
for extraccion in soup.find_all('div', class_='j-location'):
    extraccion = extraccion.text
    print(extraccion)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

He visto dos problemas por los que no funcionaba uno es el parse lo haces contra lxml y debería ser contra html. Otro es que estas recogiendo el response.text cuando debes recoger el response.content. Aquí te dejo la solución: https://repl.it/@ssolamente/PythonParse

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Encoding: UTF-8
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

print("--------------------------")
print("--------- Neuvoo ---------")
print("--------------------------")
url = "https://neuvoo.com.ar/trabajos/?k=&l=capital+federal&p=1&date=&field=&company=&source_type=&radius=&from=&test=&iam=&is_category=no"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html')
print("### Descripcion ###")
for extraccion in soup.find_all ('div', class_='j-snippet'):
    extraccion = extraccion.text
    if not (extraccion == ''):
        print(extraccion)
print("### Locacion ###")
for extraccion in soup.find_all('div', class_='j-location'):
    extraccion = extraccion.text
    print(extraccion)
```

Comment: Un millón de gracias, tendré que investigar un poco más, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Te han dado en otra respuesta una solución para que te funcione. Voy a tratar de explicar aquí por qué no funcionaba tu intento, aunque debería haber funcionado. La culpa no fue tuya :-)

### El problema

El problema es que para enviar datos por la red, es necesario convertirlos antes a una secuencia de bytes. El servidor, antes de enviarte su página HTML la convirtió en una secuencia de bytes. Si todos los caracteres de la página fuesen ASCII no habría habido ningún problema, pues la forma de convertir letras de la tabla ASCII a bytes es un estándar asumido tanto por clientes como por servidores, sin tener que especificar nada más.

Pero en el momento en que la página contiene letras que no están en la tabla ASCII (como es el caso de las vocales acentuadas o la eñe), el servidor ha tenido que elegir un mecanismo de codificación, y hay muchos posibles donde elegir. Por mencionar un par de ellos, los más habituales para páginas en español, tenemos el ISO-8859-15 (también llamado latin9), el ISO-8859-1 (también llamado `latin1`) y el UTF-8.

El caso es que el servidor ha elegido uno (ha sido el utf-8 en este caso, luego veremos cómo lo sé), pero como parte de la respuesta HTTP debe incluir una cabecera para informar al cliente de cuál ha sido el *encoding* elegido. El servidor en tu caso no ha incluido esa cabecera, como podemos ver si hacemos:

```
for clave, valor in response:
   print(clave, valor)
```

Que imprime las caberas enviadas por el servidor y muestra:

```
Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2019 08:20:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.25
Set-Cookie: uet_last_search_k=null; expires=Fri, 25-Jan-2019 09:20:25 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/, uet_last_search_l=capital+federal; expires=Fri, 25-Jan-2019 09:20:25 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 11837
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

La cabecera `Content-Type` es la que debía haberlo especificado, pues debería haber sido `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

Al no haberlo especificado, la biblioteca `requests` ha asumido un *encoding* por defecto. Podemos ver cuál ha sido así:

```
print(response.encoding)
```

y vemos `ISO-8859-1`. Según explica en [su documentación](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#encodings) esa decisión la toma para cumplir con el estándar RFC-2616

El caso es que, debido a que ese no había sido el *encoding* usado por el servidor, la decodificación de los bytes recibidos para convertirlos de nuevo en letras, falla.

Como he dicho **no era culpa tuya**, sino del servidor que no especificó la cabecera apropiada.

### Soluciones

La solución dada por @solamente consistió en usar `response.content` en lugar de `response.text` ¿por qué? ¿cuál es la diferencia?

`response.content` te da acceso a los bytes directamente, tal como los envió el servidor y sin decodificar en forma alguna. En cambio `response.text` te proporciona el texto ya decodificado, que normalmente sería correcto, pero en este caso no lo es por lo anteriormente explicado acerca de los *encodings*.

Al pasarle `response.content` a BeautifulSoup, estás dejando a éste último el trabajo de de tratar de "adivinar" cuál es el verdadero encoding de esos bytes. BeautifulSoup adivina correctamente que el encoding era UTF-8, decodifica esos bytes para convertirlos en texto, y trabaja sobre el texto resultante.

¿Cómo adivinó BeautifulSoup el verdadero encoding? Lo cierto es que lo tenía más fácil que `requests`, porque `requests` sólo mira las cabeceras HTTP y hemos visto que en ellas no viene especificado *encoding* alguno. En cambio BeautifulSoup mira *el contenido* de la respuesta, y vemos que ésta comienza así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Mejores trabajos en Capital Federal y Salarios</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Es el HTML del documento, y en su zona `<head>` vemos que tiene un tag `<meta>` en el que especifica el verdadero encoding usado por la página.

En ocasiones los servidores están tan mal configurados que incluso lo especificado en el tag `<meta>` puede ser erróneo. En ese caso incluso un navegador web mostraría mal los acentos en la página. También puede ocurrir (lo he visto muchas veces) que el encoding especificado en el HTML sea correcto, pero después este HTML incorpore partes que han sido extraidas de una base de datos que estaba usando un *encoding* diferente, mostrándose por tanto mal esas partes.

#### Otra soluciones

Se puede especificar a `requests` el encoding usado por el servidor, así:

```
result.encoding = "utf-8"
```

Una vez hecho esto, el acceso a `result.text` ya estará correcto y no necesitarás usar `result.content` Pero claro, esta solución implica que *sabemos* que el servidor usó UTF-8, lo cual a priori nos es desconocido (aunque en este caso concreto en que ya lo hemos averiguado, podemos usarlo).

Otra posibilidad es usar `chardet` para tratar de adivinar el encoding. Este es un módulo python que ya tienes instalado pues viene con `requests`. Se usaría en la forma siguiente:

```
import chardet
print(chardet.detect(response.content))
```

Como ves le pasamos los bytes directamente para que trate de adivinar cuál es el encoding de la página. `chardet` no se basa como BeautifulSoup en el tag `<meta>`, pues chardet no sabe nada de tags ni de HTML. Directamente mira la secuencia de bytes y busca ciertos patrones que suelen aparecer si la codificación fuese UTF-8, u otros bytes comunmente usados en ISO-8859-1, etc. En definitiva, usa *heurísticos* para adivinar el encoding. Por tanto esto funcionará razonablemente bien incluso si el servidor estuviera usando un tag `<meta>` erróneo.

En nuestro caso imprime:

```
{'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'language': ''}
```

Que indica que, con una confianza del 99%, el texto es `utf-8`.

Comment: ey espectacular, me sirve mucho lo que me decís para seguir aprendiendo, gracias por toda la info